# Least Squares method in practice

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, regression

Very simple regression task. I have three variables `x1, x2, x3` with some random noise. And I know target equation: `y = q1*x1 + q2*x2 + q3*x3`. Now I want to find target coefs: `q1, q2, q3` evaluate the
performance using the mean Relative Squared Error (RSE) `(Prediction/Real - 1)^2` to evaluate the performance of our prediction methods.

In the research, I see that *this is ordinary Least Squares Problem*. But I can't get from examples on the internet how to solve this particular problem in Python. Let say I have data:

```
import numpy as np

sourceData = np.random.rand(1000, 3)
koefs = np.array([1, 2, 3])
target = np.dot(sourceData, koefs)
```

(In real life that data are noisy, with not normal distribution.) How to find this koefs using Least Squares approach in python? *Any lib usage.*

Comment: No, this is not ordinary least squares problem. In ordinary least squares, you minimize the sum of squared errors. Your loss function is different. For mean absolute deviation, there is [quantile regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_regression) but I am not sure if the estimators would behave the same way when you take the percentages. Your question seems more suitable for [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) (well the statistical part - maybe not the library suggestion part).

Comment: @ayhan https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266653405_Using_early_view_patterns_to_predict_the_popularity_of_YouTube_videos here some evidence of this after some reformulation in the Multivariate Linear (ML) Model section.  "which is an ordinary least squares (OLS) problem that can
be solved via a singular value decomposition"

Comment: The loss function is not the mean absolute percentage error there.

Comment: You are right, I have changed mean absolute percentage error to Relative Squared Error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@ayhan made a valuable comment.

And there is a problem with your code: Actually there is no noise in the data you collect. The input data is noisy, but after the multiplication, you don't add any additional noise.

I've added some noise to your measurements and used the least squares formula to fit the parameters, here's my code:

```
data = np.random.rand(1000,3)

true_theta = np.array([1,2,3])
true_measurements = np.dot(data, true_theta)

noise = np.random.rand(1000) * 1

noisy_measurements = true_measurements + noise

estimated_theta = np.linalg.inv(data.T @ data) @ data.T @ noisy_measurements
```

The `estimated_theta` will be close to `true_theta`. If you don't add noise to the measurements, they will be equal.

I've used the python3 matrix multiplication syntax.
You could use `np.dot` instead of @

That makes the code longer, so I've split the formula:

```
MTM_inv = np.linalg.inv(np.dot(data.T, data))
MTy = np.dot(data.T, noisy_measurements)
estimated_theta = np.dot(MTM_inv, MTy)
```

You can read up on least squares here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)#The_general_problem

**UPDATE:**

Or you could just use the [builtin least squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html) function:

```
np.linalg.lstsq(data, noisy_measurements)
```

Comment: Very cool thanks.. is it the same as numpy.linalg.lstsq? Unfortunately, I can't provide loss to take care of outliers in the data

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that function. It seems like your comment would be the perfect answer ;)  - Yes, that function would be the same. Potentially even better. I don't know the interna of their implementation

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the @lhk answer I have found great scipy [Least Squares function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html). It is easy to get the requested behavior with it.

This way we can provide a custom function that returns residuals and form Relative Squared Error instead of absolute squared difference:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import least_squares
data = np.random.rand(1000,3)

true_theta = np.array([1,2,3])
true_measurements = np.dot(data, true_theta)

noise = np.random.rand(1000) * 1

noisy_measurements = true_measurements + noise
#noisy_measurements[-1] = data[-1]  @ (1000 * true_theta) - uncoment this outliner to see how much Relative Squared Error esimator works better then default abs diff for this case.


def my_func(params, x, y):
     res = (x @ params) / y - 1 # If we change this line to: (x @ params) - y - we will got the same result as np.linalg.lstsq
     return res

res = least_squares(my_func, x0,  args=(data, noisy_measurements) ) 
estimated_theta = res.x
```

Also, we can provide custom loss with `loss` argument function that will process the residuals and form final loss.